# what is the pysvn command equvilent to "svn info file:///path/to/svn/repo"?

Tags: python, svn

I'm looking for a good python library to manipulate subversion repositories. I'm trying out [PySvn](http://pysvn.tigris.org/), but finding that it can't handle something like

```
pysvn.Client().info("/path/to/svn/repo")
```

because it's not a working copy. Anyone know of any good libraries that can handle this kind of thing?

**Update** - I'll try to simplify it - I want to get info about the repository. The same kind of info I get when I run `svn info file:///path/to/svn/repo`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: In the context of a SVN *client*, referring to a repository by *pathname* is *never* the right thing to do; repositories must be referred to by URLs, and only working copy items are referred to by paths. That said, in a library/API context you might need to use different calls for the two cases as devcooch suggests (I haven't used C or python svn APIs). I can just say that it's definitely wrong to be referring to a repository, from the client side, using a pathname.

Comment: ok then, I'll try to simplify it - I want to get info about the repository. The same kind of info I get when I run `svn info file:///path/to/svn/repo`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you try info2 instead of info? Documentation says it can access URL of repository.

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I wanted, (but with recurse=False). Thanks.